# Change the slug ( url ) to a sequence number starting from 0 in the custom record type?

Tags: url-rewriting, slug

A notionally custom post type is created - mods
I want url to be of type site.com/mods/**XXXX** where XXXX is serial number in category (not global ID(%post_id%)) That is it starts with 0 and goes further 1...2...3...

Comment: @SallyCJ I do not quite understand, can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. So, you're trying to have the post slug be a number, right? E.g. `site.com/mods/0`, `site.com/mods/1`, `site.com/mods/2`, etc.

Comment: Yes 
there is an idea to use a chain of plugins
ACF + permalink manager 
https://permalinkmanager.pro/docs/tutorials/how-to-use-custom-fields-inside-wordpress-permalinks/

Like create a modid field and add 1 to it each time you create a post
And permalink manager will have the mask site.com/mods/%__modid%.


But my knowledge in Wordpress and php at the level of a beginner, so I'm learning by trial and error, I would be glad if you tell me the code)

The number to which add +1 can be taken from the function wp_count_posts()

Comment: I see. Are you going to do this just for certain [post statuses](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-status/)? Will the modid values be grouped according to the post status? I.e. Post A - modid 1, Post B - modid 2, Post C - modid 1, Post D - modid 2, Post E - modid 3, where posts A, B and E are published, whereas posts C and D are private. (PS: I deleted my very 1st comment)

Comment: @SallyCJ Posts will first have a status in moderation If you mean how to count posts, then count posts that have already been published